# How to change format mask of date picker while printing with Apex Office Print?

Tags: datepicker, timestamp, oracle-apex

In APEX I have a date picker with format mask: DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI

But when I print my report with AOP it looks something like: 2020-04-15T11:02:00.000000Z

How can I change this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date data is stored in the database in a date format, the APEX format mask is just that - a mask.

I guess this really depends how you're running your report, but I would suggest using to_char() in your SQL that you feed to AOP.

```
to_char(date_field, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') "template_alias"
```